# OpenLayers on iPhone with navigation: marker-click event won't work

Tags: openlayers-2, mobile, iphone

I'm making a map with openlayers. For the navigation on the iPhone I added OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(), so zoom and pan work fine.
On the desktop, i can click a marker and a popup appears.
But on the phone nothing happens?

Any suggestions?

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {projection: mercator,
    controls: [



        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults()

        ],
        units: 'meters',
});



temp = tCoord(lon, lat);
        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markerLayer, temp);
        feature.closeBox = true;
        feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored, {minSize: new OpenLayers.Size(320, 100)} );
        feature.data.popupContentHTML = "<div class=\"infoWindow\"><strong>" + name +"</strong> <br/>" + desc 
                                        +"<br><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"routing(new OpenLayers.LonLat("+lon+","+ lat+"))\">Route hierher</a></div>";
        feature.data.overflow = "hidden";

        var tempMarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(temp, icon.clone());
        tempMarker.feature = feature;
         tempMarker.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);
        allPoints.push(new Array(zeilenCounter, tempMarker));
```

(tCoord transforms from wgs84 to spherical mercator)

Answer (score 2):

first of all use OpenLayers.Mobile library for developing mobile application, [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.mobile.js). and then checkout these if u consider or not.

1. `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`
2. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">`
3. controls in map options:

   ```
     controls: [
       new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({
           dragPanOptions: {
               enableKinetic: true
           }
       }),
       new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom(),
       toolbar
                ]
   ```

beside this you can glance at openlayers mobile jquery app [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-jq.html#mappage) as to some viewpoint.

i hope it helps you...